# SWRevealViewController stop tap gesture when user is in frontView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using `SWRevealViewController`  for sliding menu. I have added tap gesture in the front view using:

```
SWRevealViewController *revealController = [self revealViewController];

[revealController tapGestureRecognizer];
```

My tap gesture is working. But problem is that my front view has button which require the taps to navigate to other screens. IS there any way to disable the tap gesture when frontView is enabled and enable tap Gesture when menu is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you tried this

create the delegate on your class

```
@interface xxxViewController () <SWRevealViewControllerDelegate>
```

on delegate method as

```
  - (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController willMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position
{
    if (position == FrontViewPositionLeftSide) {
        self.tapGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
        // disable your current class action

    }
    else if (position == FrontViewPositionLeft){
        self.tapGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
        // enable your current class action


    }
}
```

Comment: `self.tapGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;`  is of revealController? i.e In revealController there is the method `[revealController tapGestureRecognizer];`. How to enable and disable this?

Comment: ya yes bro....., see this once https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/92

Answer (score 0):

`Import SWRevealViewController.h` in your slide out menu class. Then in your sliding menu `viewWillAppear` method put this line-

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

   self.revealViewController.frontViewController.revealViewController.tapGestureRecognizer.enabled=false;

}
```

and in `viewWillDisappear` method put this line-

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{

self.revealViewController.frontViewController.revealViewController.tapGestureRecognizer.enabled=true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Front view controller add this**

```
SWRevealViewController *objRevealViewController = [self revealViewController];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:objRevealViewController.tapGestureRecognizer];
```